# Using BeautifulSoup to scrape website and content of other urls from the website

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

**Context**

I'm trying to scrape a company website (I have permission) and extract job positions from their job section.

All the positions are listed with high level details on the first page (directory), however the details for the positions are on unique urls. I want to enable my scraper to be able to identify the relevant positions in the directory and then scrape the unique urls.

**Code I have written so far**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

url = "http://implementconsultinggroup.com/career/#/6257"
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

links = soup.find_all("a")

for link in links:
     if "career" in link.get("href") and 'COPENHAGEN' in link.text:
             print "<a href='%s'>%s</a>" %(link.get("href"), link.text)
```

Which gives me the following output:

```
View Position

</a>
<a href='/career/business-analyst-within-human-capital-management/'>
Business analyst within human capital management
COPENHAGEN • We are looking for an ambitious student with an interest in HR 
who is passionate about working in the cross-field of people management, 
business and technology




View Position

</a>
<a href='/career/management-consultants-within-strategic-workforce-planning/'>
Management consultants within strategic workforce planning
COPENHAGEN • We are looking for consultants with profound experience from 
other consultancies
```

I would like the scraper to scrape all content from the output above. So scrape through the URLS and extract the content of those pages.

Would be great if someone know how to do that or can direct me to a guide on how to create this feature for my scraper.

**Expected Output**

I want the scraper to access the urls above which brings me to the actual job posting pages (http://implementconsultinggroup.com/career/management-consultants-within-strategic-workforce-planning/) and then extract the details from that page.

*Management consultants within strategic workforce planning
At Implement Consulting Group, we wish to make a difference in the consulting industry, because we believe that the ability to create change with impact is a precondition for success in an increasingly global and turbulent world.
We experience a highly increased intake of exciting projects, and therefore we are looking for competent colleagues with profound knowledge of working with management and who wish to create real impact for our clients in collaboration with a team of inspiring colleagues.
Job content – Change with Impact
The job content varies, but includes:
Designing workforce strategy that links and supports business strategy
Implementation of strategic workforce planning
Assisting in building an ambitious and data-driven approach to workforce planning
Implementing talent, career and performance management programmes
Developing and optimising HR processes
HRIS and HR digitisation
Providing consultancy services in relation to developing HR strategies
Assisting in developing the team and the area of expertise
Our projects are wide-ranging and typically include optimisation of management tools and processes within HR, people performance management solutions and the establishment of organisational excellence. Part of our mission is to continuously improve our leadership behaviour and be the most attractive place to work.
We are looking for people who
Hold at least one relevant master’s degree
As a minimum have 3-5 years of experience, preferably from other consultancies
Have experience in designing and implementing strategic and/or operational workforce planning
Have the ability and the desire to connect workforce strategy with business strategy
Have the ability to establish a good co-operation with clients at all organisational levels
Are able to solve problems and lead teams
You are passionate about creating results, and you believe in an appreciative approach in the execution of change. You can be normative, but are aware that nothing is black and white. You love diversity, and you are both analytical and empathic. In your future job, you wish to take on both the role of adviser and project manager, and you are interested in working with several aspects of the job as a consultant.
What do we offer?
We offer an attractive performancerelated remuneration package as well as excellent development opportunities among highly competent and ambitious colleagues. We work with a high degree of freedom with responsibility and support each other in our efforts to constantly become better at helping our clients create exceptional results. We offer a truly unique culture, a network of helpful colleagues and a company trying to change the business of consultancy to create change with impact.
 Apply
For further information about the position, please contact Julius M. Opstrup, +45 2338 0004. For further information about the recruitment process, please contact Julie Palmqvist, +45 6124 4847.
The application deadline is as soon as possible. We look forward to hearing from you!
Visit our career page to learn more about a career at Implement Consulting Group or learn more about our Copenhagen office.*

Comment: and why do you reconstruct tags in the loop?

Comment: I just tried to clarify the expected output above. 

@Dmitriy - no specific reason. How would you create the loop instead?

Comment: @PalleBroe, do you need FULL descriptions of jobs or thort ones on the job list page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think nothing else is there to scrape. Run it and see for yourself:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

base = "http://implementconsultinggroup.com"
url = "http://implementconsultinggroup.com/career/#/6257"

req = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(req,'html.parser')
links = soup.select("a.box-link")

for link in links:
    res = requests.get(base + link.get("href")).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res,'html.parser')
    title = soup.select_one("h1.section__title").get_text() if soup.select_one("h1.section__title") else ""
    details = soup.select_one("div.rte").get_text()
    print(title, details)
```

Comment: Thanks Mithu! This seems to be working well! 

One questions around the title - I have added to the above.

Comment: If it works make sure to press the up vote button and accept it as an answer. I'm not around my pc at this moment. As soon as I'm I will take a look at your additional question. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks - already pressed +1 and look forward to your answer on the question above.

Comment: Hi Mithu - any chance you could have a look at the above?

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

url = "http://implementconsultinggroup.com/career/#/6257"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

position_block = soup.find('ul', class_="list-articles")
position_list = position_block.find_all('li')

position_links = []

for position in position_list:
    position_links.append(position.a['href'])


base_url = "http://implementconsultinggroup.com"

descriptions = []

for link in position_links:
    r = requests.get(base_url + link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

    descriptions.append(soup.find('div', class_='contentwithrelated').get_text())
```

Comment: @PalleBroe, any feedback on my solution?

Comment: My feedback is that code-only solutions have limited value for future readers, since it does not immediately show the essence of the solution. If you can prefix this with a sentence or two of text that describes what you were thinking as you wrote this, that is often very useful.

Comment: Hi Dmitriy, 

I could not get it to run, but it seems that Mithus code above is working great. Thanks for the help though.